# What kind of database should I use for storing or retrieving files?

Tags: database

If I have thousands of binary/non-text files that can be loaded by a program, then scanning the root directory and loading each path into memory at runtime is obviously a terrible idea, especially if there won't be more than a couple being read/written at once. Therefore, I think I should be writing/reading those paths from disk. I'm thinking about what Arxiv uses for example. I highly doubt that they actually store the binary data to all the pdfs inside a database, but rather just relative/absolute paths. Which type of database would suit this kind of usage better for a client-sided application?

I thought I'd look into MongoDB, but it's not the "document-oriented database" I was thinking of. SQL databases could work? But then I'd just be storing a bunch of relative paths and I'm not sure if that's the proper way to do things.

Comment: You can choose any database you want, depending on your specific needs, as long as you're able to model your queryable data the way you want to, and the database integrates with your code, 3rd-party tools, etc. And then store your non-searchable data wherever you want that supports bulk storage, with uri pointing to the non-searchable/binary data. There's no possible way to provide an objectively-correct database recommendation (whether *type* of database, like document or graph, or *specific brand* such as MongoDB, the one you mentioned).

Comment: Also: not sure what you mean by MongoDB not being the document-oriented database you were thinking of: it's a document-store database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have a single right answer so it's likely to be closed as too vague or opinion-based. It might be better asked on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) but may be considered too opinion-based there as well (unless framed as a "what are the pros and cons of doing X vs Y" or perhaps a "Are there other options?" question)

However, the general practical answer is "store metadata in your database; store your files in a place that makes sense for files." Most relational databases now have a passable solution for BLOB storage, but the network and disk cost characteristics often make this an inefficient solution.

My default solution is to store files on some sort of S3-like object store, and reference the path in my usual database (postgres, for example, or, depending on the types of search features required, something like ElasticSearch). I typically serve these files using a CDN (Cloudfront can work). If there's some sort of permissions model to enforce, I'll use signed URLs or signed cookies.

Comment: This would be off-topic on [softwareengineering.se] as well, just as it is here.